# SQLite syntax to create index on a temp table?

Tags: sqlite, indexing

The syntax to create a table is

```
CREATE [temp] TABLE TableName(...)
```

so  table can be created in the temp database using

```
CREATE temp TABLE MyTable(...)
```

or

```
 CREATE TABLE temp.MyTable(...)
```

and the fully resolved way to refer to that table would be

```
temp.Mytable
```

**which would be a different table to main.MyTable.**

However, the syntax to create an index is just

```
CREATE INDEX IndexName ON TableName (FieldName )
```

which does not allow the table name to have the database name prepended

so this is OK

```
CREATE INDEX MyIndex ON MyTable (MyField)
```

but this is not

```
CREATE INDEX MyIndex ON Temp.MyTable (MyField)
```

How then can I create an index on a temp table (especially if there might be table of the same name in the main database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The database name must be put on the index name:

```
CREATE INDEX temp.MyIndex ON MyTable(MyField)
```

Comment: Ah, so it is. Thank you. That's a slightly different syntax to other places where one refers to a table. I guess SQLite assumes you mean the temp version of the table rather than the main version with the same name because you are making a temp index